# Synchronized template wrapper class

Tags: c++, thread-safety, template

> **Issue**: Code base has lots of data structures which are accessed between threads with >= 1 writer. Application logic becomes obfuscated due to lots of mutex locks.
>
> **Solution**: Create a template class which provides synchronized access through member functions.

This seems very hacky -- Is this a futile effort / antipattern?

```
#ifndef SYNCHRONIZED_HPP_
#define SYNCHRONIZED_HPP_

#include <functional>
#include <mutex>
#include <shared_mutex>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>


#undef DISALLOW_EVIL_CONSTRUCTORS
#define DISALLOW_EVIL_CONSTRUCTORS(TypeName) \
  TypeName(const TypeName&);                 \
  void operator=(const TypeName&)


template <typename T>
class synchronized;

template <typename T> auto
make_synchronized(T&& value) {
  return synchronized<T>{ std::forward<T>(value) };
}

template <typename T>
class synchronized final {
 public:
  using value_t = std::remove_reference_t<T>;

  template <typename... Args>
  explicit synchronized(Args&&... args)
    : value_(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
  {}

  value_t get() const {
    read_lock l(mutex_);
    return value_;
  }
  
  template <typename U> void
  set(U&& new_value) {
    write_lock l(mutex_);
    value_ = std::forward<U>(new_value);
  }
  
  template <typename Accessor>
  void use(Accessor&& access) const {
    read_lock l(mutex_);
    std::forward<Accessor>(access)(value_);
  }

  template <typename Mutator>
  void alter(Mutator&& func) {
    write_lock l(mutex_);
    std::forward<Mutator>(func)(value_);
  }

 private:
  value_t value_;
  using mutex_t = std::shared_timed_mutex;
  using read_lock = std::shared_lock<mutex_t>;
  using write_lock = std::unique_lock<mutex_t>;
  mutable mutex_t mutex_{};

  DISALLOW_EVIL_CONSTRUCTORS(synchronized);
};


#endif // SYNCHRONIZED_HPP_
```

**With doxy comments (same code)**:

```
#ifndef SYNCHRONIZED_HPP_
#define SYNCHRONIZED_HPP_

#include <functional>
#include <mutex>
#include <shared_mutex>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>


#undef DISALLOW_EVIL_CONSTRUCTORS
#define DISALLOW_EVIL_CONSTRUCTORS(TypeName) \
  TypeName(const TypeName&);                 \
  void operator=(const TypeName&)





template <typename T>
class synchronized;


/**
* @brief
*    Make a synchronized<T> using template deduction.
*
* @sa synchronized
*/
template <typename T> auto
make_synchronized(T&& value) {
  return synchronized<T>{ std::forward<T>(value) };
}

/**
* @brief
*    Provides straightforward thread-synchronized access to template type.
*
* @note
*    While access to the immediate type is synchronized, this class does not
*  prevent non-synchronized access of pointer or reference members of the
*  template type.
*
* @note
*    For applicable types, prefer std::atomic<T>.
*/
template <typename T>
class synchronized final {
 public:
  using value_t = std::remove_reference_t<T>;

  template <typename... Args>
  explicit synchronized(Args&&... args)
    : value_(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
  {}

  /**
  * @brief
  *    Thread-sychronized get.
  */
  value_t get() const {
    read_lock l(mutex_);
    return value_;
  }

  /**
  * @brief
  *    Thread-sychronized set.
  */
  template <typename U> void
  set(U&& new_value) {
    write_lock l(mutex_);
    value_ = std::forward<U>(new_value);
  }

  /**
  * @brief
  *    Use the underlying value where get() would be less-trivial or
  *  otherwise unsuitable.
  *
  * @note
  *    Prefer get(), especially if this access takes a long time, as to not
  *  starve a writer thread or other reader threads.
  */
  template <typename Accessor>
  void use(Accessor&& access) const {
    read_lock l(mutex_);
    std::forward<Accessor>(access)(value_);
  }

  /**
  * @brief
  *    Alter (mutate) the underlying value where get() and set() would be
  *  less-trivial or otherwise unsuitable.
  *
  * @note
  *    Prefer the combination of get() then set(), especially if this access
  *  takes a long time, as to not starve other writer or reader threads.
  */
  template <typename Mutator>
  void alter(Mutator&& func) {
    write_lock l(mutex_);
    std::forward<Mutator>(func)(value_);
  }

 private:
  value_t value_;
  using mutex_t = std::shared_timed_mutex;
  using read_lock = std::shared_lock<mutex_t>;
  using write_lock = std::unique_lock<mutex_t>;
  mutable mutex_t mutex_{};

  DISALLOW_EVIL_CONSTRUCTORS(synchronized);
};


#endif // SYNCHRONIZED_HPP_
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like a decent implementation. You should be aware that *nothing* in this area is foolproof. Two ways to "break" your code are:

```
auto si = make_synchronized(42);
// ...
int *one;
si.alter([&](int& val) {
    one = &val;
});
*one = 42;  // use outside of the lock
```

and

```
auto si = make_synchronized(42);
auto& si2 = si;
// ...
si.use([&](const int&) {
    si2.alter([&](int&) {
        // deadlock
    });
});
```

But this is no big deal, as long as you trust your users (which might mean yourself!) to avoid getting into this kind of situation. The second situation above (deadlock) is particularly easy to hide by placing the second `si.alter` inside a helper function, or by aliasing the way I did with `si2`.

---

```
#undef DISALLOW_EVIL_CONSTRUCTORS
#define DISALLOW_EVIL_CONSTRUCTORS(TypeName) \
  TypeName(const TypeName&);                 \
  void operator=(const TypeName&)
```

At least three issues here. First, you should be using `=delete` instead of this macro. Simply:

```
template <typename T>
class synchronized final {
public:
    synchronized(synchronized&&) = delete;
    synchronized(const synchronized&) = delete;
    synchronized& operator=(synchronized&&) = delete;
    synchronized& operator=(const synchronized&) = delete;
```

(Once you've explicitly `=delete`d the move operations, further `=delete`ing the copy operations is unnecessary... but recommended, for clarity.)

Second, although it doesn't apply too much in this specific case, having a macro that consists of multiple statements or declarations is usually a red flag. Look up "hygienic macros in C" for more information on the `do { ... } while (0)` idiom.

Third, you're using

```
#undef X
#define X Y
```

as a way to say "I really really want `X` to mean `Y`, even if someone else has already defined `X` to mean something different." That's probably a bad idea. If nobody else has previously defined `X`, then your `#undef` is redundant (and should be removed). If someone else *has* previously defined `X`, then your `#undef` makes your own code work but presumably breaks whatever *that* person was using `X` for! Rather than redefine `X` in a way that might break their code down the line, it would be much much better to just error out right here in that case (so again, the solution is to remove the `#undef`).

---

I notice the `final` keyword on `class synchronized`. Why is it important to you that this class be `final`?

---

```
template <typename Accessor>
void use(Accessor&& access) const {
  read_lock l(mutex_);
  std::forward<Accessor>(access)(value_);
}
```

Perfect forwarding here is fine, but almost certainly overkill. I can't think of any case where I'd want the accessor itself to be either non-const or an rvalue. The accessor should *always* be of the form `[&](const auto& value) { ... }`; it never needs to have any captures that could be affected by `mutable`, and thus it never needs to be called as non-const. So we can simplify:

```
template<class Accessor>
void use(const Accessor& access) const {
    read_lock l(mutex_);
    access(value_);
}
```

(Incidentally, anything other than four-space indents is horrible. :))

---

```
template <typename T> auto
make_synchronized(T&& value) {
  return synchronized<T>{ std::forward<T>(value) };
}
```

Looks good, but...

- The `auto` here isn't buying you anything; it might be better to give the return type explicitly as `synchronized<T>`.
- The curly braces in `synchronized<T>{ ... }` are inconsistent with the way `make_` functions work everywhere else in the Standard Library. `make_shared` uses parens. `make_unique` uses parens. To observe the difference, make a class `A` where `A{...}` and `A(...)` call different constructors, [like this](https://godbolt.org/z/mB7ov_). (`make_pair` and `make_tuple` also use parens, although I'm not sure if the difference is observable in those two cases.)

Comment: Excellent and very thorough answer. I did not consider the possible deadlock. And thank you for pointing out the antiquated and flawed macro (must have been inspired by pre-c++11 code), the needless perfect forwarding, and showing that `T()` and `T{}` are not semantically identical (that was a gap in my knowledge until now).
#Two-spaces for life (;

Comment: To answer your question, `final` was not necessary. Perhaps only me pre-criticizing inheriting developers.